# Reference from field to another field in Joomla xml

Tags: xml, templates, joomla, parameters, filelist

I am adding some parameters to my template backend in Joomla 2.5. With the first one I want the user to select a folder.

```
<field name="folder" type="folderlist" directory="/images" label="TPL_NAME_PARAMETER_FOLDER_LABEL" description="TPL_NAME_PARAMETER_FOLDER_DESC"/>
```

With the second one I would like to have the user choose a file from ***the chosen folder from the first field***

```
<field name="file" type="filelist" directory="CHOSEN_FOLDER" label="TPL_NAME_PARAMETER_FILE_LABEL" description="TPL_NAME_PARAMETER_FILE_DESC" />
```

From what I already read this is not possible from inside the .xml file? Anybody got a workaround for this? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go through all the code but basically you would have to call an element by using the `<params addpath="">` method. The you would need to create a PHP file called "folderlist", and add the code to override the select list.

```
jimport('joomla.html.html');
jimport('joomla.html.parameter.element');

class JElementFolderlist extends JElement {

//functions go in here

}
```

You would need to do the same for the filelist.php but in this file, add in some javascript so load a new list of files, according to what had been selected from the folderlist.php.

I know this isn't a full answer with all the code you need, but its to get you started off.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll work on it and give further feedback :)

Comment: So after first readings, shouldn't I rather override the files in the form folder using `class JFormFieldFileList extends JFormFieldList`? The parameter files in the html folder are marked as deprecated.

Comment: I didn't use this when I did it not too long ago though, however mine was for a Kunena Template., so you might be right.